# How to use CreateInBoundsGEP in cpp api of llvm to access the element of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, llvm-c++-api

I am new to llvm programming, and I am trying to write cpp to generate llvm ir for a simple C code like this:

```
int a[10];
a[0] = 1;
```

I want to generate something like this to store 1 into a[0]

```
%3 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %2, i64 0, i64 0
store i32 1, i32* %3, align 16
```

And I tried `CreateGEP`: `auto arrayPtr = builder.CreateInBoundsGEP(var, num);` where `var` and 
 `num` are both of type `llvm::Value*`

but I only get

```
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %0, i32 0
  store i32 1, [10 x i32]* %1
```

I searched google for a long time and looked the llvm manual but still don't know what Cpp api to use and how to use it.

Really appreciate it if you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the 2nd argument to [`IRBuilder::CreateInBoundsGEP` (1st overload)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#a1c8c3647830f37bf3c338ef3999f228d) is actually `ArrayRef<Value *>`, which means it accepts an array of `Value *` values (including C-style array, `std::vector<Value *>` and `std::array<Value *, LEN>` and others).

To generate a GEP instruction with multiple (child) addresses, pass an array of `Value *` to the second argument:

```cpp
Value *i32zero = ConstantInt::get(contexet, APInt(32, 0));
Value *indices[2] = {i32zero, i32zero};
builder.CreateInBoundsGEP(var, ArrayRef<Value *>(indices, 2));
```

Which will yield

```
%1 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32], [10 x i32]* %0, i32 0, i32 0
```

You can correctly identify that `%1` is of type `i32*`, pointing to the first item in the array pointed to by `%0`.

LLVM documentation on GEP instruction: https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html